# «Теперь» в предложении-дополнении

Tags: пунктуация

«Мальчик(,) теперь уже вместе с родителями(,) вышел из класса». 
Нужно ли обособлять этот, как бы сказать, оборот, это дополнение? Вроде как интонационно выделяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Мальчик, теперь уже вместе с родителями, вышел из класса.***

Выделяется. Интонационно. Не обособить эту конструкцию не представляется возможным.

Почему? Простое предложение без обособленных членов интонационно делится паузой **на две части** (тема — рема): обычно повышение голоса в конце первой части — пауза — понижение голоса в конце предложения.

Как поделить это предложение на две фразы? *Мальчик теперь уже вместе с родителями //вышел из класса.* **Нет, не получится.** Поэтому оборот обособляется.

Сравнить: *Мальчик вместе с родителями // вышел из класса*.

Comment: Теперь ясненько. :) Благодарю!